# Creating multiple test suites in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, mocha.js

I am writing testing script using selenium webdriver, phantomJS, Mocha.

My scripts are javascript files.

This are my variables, declared outside the test modules:

```
var afterLoginURL;
var afterLoginTitle;
var loginFlag = 0;
```

I have two test modules:

```
test.describe('Site Login Test', function() 
{
    test.it('User Login', function() 
    {
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
                    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
                    .build();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) 
        {
            if(expectedTitle === title) /* if the title matches */
            {
                driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys(username); 
                driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys(password);
                driver.findElement(By.id('_submit')).click();

                if(username.length > 0 && password.length > 0)
                {
                    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Log out')]")).then(function(elem)
                    {
                        if(elem.length > 0)
                             loginFlag = 1;
                        else
                             console.log("Login Unsuccessful");
                        if(loginFlag == 1)
                        {
                            console.log("Login Successful");
                            // after login, we are in the dashboard page, counting a side menu <li> //
                            driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id, 'sidemenu')]/li")).then(function(liSize)
                            {
                                console.log(liSize);
                            });
                            driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
                                afterLoginURL = url;
                            });
                            driver.getTitle().then(function(title){
                                afterLoginTitle =  title;
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log("Login Unsuccessful");
                        }   
                    });
                }
            }
            else    /* if the title doesn't match */
            {
                console.log("Verification Failed - An incorrect title.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Now, in the next test module, I am directly navigating to the dashboard page and then check for the same `<ul>` and `<li>`, but it seems the code is not able to locate the element:

```
test.describe('Menu Test', function() 
{
    test.it('Detect Menu', function() 
    {
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
                        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
                        .build();
        if(loginFlag == 1)
        {
            console.log("afterLoginURL :" +afterLoginURL);
            console.log("afterLoginTitle :" +afterLoginTitle);
            driver.get(afterLoginURL);    
            driver.getTitle().then(function(title) 
            {
                if(afterLoginTitle === title)
                {
                    console.log("Visited After Login Page");

                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id, 'sidemenu')]/li")).then(function(elem){
                    console.log(elem.length);
                    // getting error in this section;
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("Something wrong has happened. Much bigger than calamity");
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Not logged in");
        }
        driver.quit();
    });
});
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
NoSuchElementError: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath 
'//ul[contains(@id, 'sidemenu')]/li'"
```

What am I doing wrong over here?

Is it because the session got exhausted? How can I revisit the dashboard page(in other test module) without the session-expiry to detect the menu?

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse" id="sidemenu">
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/user/">All Users</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/company/">All Companies</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/device/">Devices</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/email/">Send Email</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/impersonate">Impersonate User</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/encrypttest">Test Encryption</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Will you please share your html?

Comment: I have added HTML sir, @J.Lyu

Comment: you have created a new web driver in the second test. The problem is that the driven in first test and the second are different. So try to have a general web driver for both tests. That should work for you. please let me know if you have more questions

Comment: @Radu, How can I have general web driver? I declared the driver outside the test suits. Still it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: @SunainaSingh I am wondering, why you are using 'side-menu' per your error message while having id='sidemenu' in your html

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It will be **sidemenu** in error message

Comment: @SunainaSingh one question does the second test open a new browser window so you have 2 browser windows?

Comment: @SunainaSingh the menu is in the page or is under an iframe?

Comment: @Radu, I am sorry if I am confusing you.  I am not opening it in any browser. I am just using phantomJS()(not firefox() or chrome()). So I think I am not opening it in any browser. I am new to selenium. I migt have made some silly mistake explaining it to you,

Comment: @Radu, the menu is under a page. No iframe is applied.

Comment: @SunainaSingh I am unable to perform test about this but firstly you can try to archive another element like the **ul** itself or others on the dashboard page. Secondly you may have a try to delay some millseconds.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try a CSS selector,

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sidemenu > li")).then(function(elem){
                console.log(elem.length);
                // getting error in this section;
                });
```

This CSS selector is looking for an element with ID (#) sidemenu that has child `LI`s. There are several given the HTML you provided.

BTW... what is `elem.length` supposed to print? Did you mean to use `.findElementS()` instead and print the number of elements found?

Comment: you are right, it should be findElements(), not findElement(). I made a typo there. But still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: What specific error are you getting when running the above code?